# gitlab custom the file path of project

Tags: gitlab

when create project in gitlab, the path is determined.
for example, assume my username is 'peter', and project name is 'test'
the path will be 'peter/test'.

Is it possible to change the path to what I want? like 'kr/peter/test'?

Comment: What does 'kr' stand for/why do you want this in the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project path is always determined by the combination of user/group and project name. If you don't want the project to be in `peter` namespace then you can create another group called 'other' and the path will then be 'other/test'. However, you cannot change the depth of the path as you suggest with `kr/peter/test`.

Comment: Is it in 2020'?